# WPF TreeView Indentation is missing

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeview

I have a TreeView which is binded to a OberservableCollection. When I add Items to that List everything works, except that the indentation of the TreeView is missing. All TreeViewItems have the same level of indentation, regardless of their level insinde the treeview. The problem with that is that you can't really see which element is at which level.

The Item class contains a list of other Items called "Children", a string called "ItemName" and a BitmapImage called "ImageSource".
I already tried it without bindings. I simply added new TreeViewItems on events, but I had the same problem with that.

Here is my XAML Code for that TreeView:

```
<TreeView Grid.Column="0" Name="ProjectTree" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewItems:Item}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="22"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Margin="1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

The bindings are fine, as I said. It is only the indentation that doesn't work.

I'd be glad if you people could help me.

Comment: Have tried adding HierarchicalDataTemplate inside TreeView.ItemTemplate instead of TreeView.Resources?

Comment: Yeah I alrady tried that. It didn't make a difference

Comment: I found the answer:
I did my sorting inside the Items attribute of the TreeView and transfered this with twoway-binding to the ObservableCollection. Now I only edit the ObservableCollection and it works.